# Advance Multi-Select - Obsolete?

Tags: custom-fields

When I was editing a custom field I got this pop-up:

'Obsolete widget
The old "Advance Multi-Select" widget is being phased out and will be removed in a future version of CiviCRM. "Multi-Select" is the recommended substitute.'

Our user find it quite nice to be able to move items between the two lists rather than remember to hold down the Ctrl key or else they lose all their previous selections.

Can anyone shed any light on why this field type is going obsolete and if there is any way of continuing to use something similar?

Had a search around and couldn't find any info.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 6):

You may be thinking of the old multi-select widget, which required Ctrl+click. The new one is much improved (I think it was refreshed in 4.5) using the popular Select2 widget. It does find-as-you-type, and as it narrows down the options you can either click or press enter to add that option, then continue with the next one. You can also click in the field for a drop-down of all options (except the ones you've already chosen). Give it a shot on the Civi demo site; I'm sure you will like it.

Comment: Thanks Nicholai, One of those moments where I realise I should have looked at the demo site before posting, indeed the new widget does look pretty good and easy to use :-) I'll have to go through and change the field types over.